# Position fixed with relative parent not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have 2 columns, the left is a list, the right shows information from the selected element from the list.

Since the list is big, I made the right one staying fixed when the div reaches the top of the window, imitating the bootstrap affix behavior but using a custom directive to do that.

I had to make the parent div (module-description) `relative` so it scrolls to the top and there, I add the class `sticky` to the child div (using the directive) so it stays `fixed` and remove it on scroll up.

This is the html from the right column:

```
<div class="animated delay fade-in-right module-description">
  <div id="module-panel" class="panel" affix affix-on-refresh="scrollTop" affix-offset-class="top"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the css affecting those 2 divs:

```
.module-description {
  float: right;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;

  .panel {
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 555px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}
```

With this said, all of this works beautifully on Chrome, but in Firefox, even tho the class `sticky` is applied, the right column does not fix at the top, just keeps scrolling up.

I'm assuming this is come kind of compatibility and that's why I'm not bothering to show my directive, but if it seems necessary, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have discovered that the problem was the css `animated` property, more specifically the `animation-fill-mode: both;` used with the position fixed.

I changed it to `animation-fill-mode: backwards;` (more on that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)) and it did the trick!